# how can i fix my 2.3.5 rails app from (CVE-2013-0156) without upgrading rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

when i use the ActionController::Base.param_parsers.delete(Mime::XML) in the environment.rb it breaks it, i put it outside the initialization block at the en of the file.

i am using nginx/passenger and the the funny thing is that when i add ActionController::Base.param_parsers.delete(Mime::XML) to my dev instance it does fix the issue but when i deploy it to production it breaks everything.

I really don't want to upgrade to rails 3 because this is legacy code, i am working on a side project to do it but for now i just want to have a secure app.

Thank you.

Comment: First, you can update to rails 2.3.15 to receive the fix. Second, "It breaks It", could you be more specific? What error message do you receive in production?

Comment: i don't want to sound stupid but, isn't going from 2.3.5 to 2.3.15 downgrading?

Comment: Nope, if you were going to treat it like a decimal you would be right. But version numbers are not actually decimals. It goes: 2.3.9, 2.3.10, 2.3.11. Each number is treated by itself. 2.3.15 is the latest 2.3.x version of the Rails gem. You can look at the Gem's release history, and see that it was released on the 8th, the same day as all the other security fix releases: http://rubygems.org/gems/rails

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a mostly typical ./config/environment.rb file?

I put it in two places: in the initializer and just before the final "end" keyword. YMMV.

```
# ./config/environment.rb
Rails::Initializer.run do |config|
  ...
  ActiveSupport::CoreExtensions::Hash::Conversions::XML_PARSING.delete('symbol')
  ActiveSupport::CoreExtensions::Hash::Conversions::XML_PARSING.delete('yaml')
end
ActiveSupport::CoreExtensions::Hash::Conversions::XML_PARSING.delete('symbol')
ActiveSupport::CoreExtensions::Hash::Conversions::XML_PARSING.delete('yaml')
```

To verify it works, run this for rails 2.x using your local dev server:

```
curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/xml" -X POST \
  -d '<id type="yaml">--- !ruby/object:ActionController::Base bar: 1</id>' \
  http://localhost:3000
```

Look in your log. If the params[:id] is an object, then you are vulnerable. 
If it's just a string, then your fix worked. [Thanks to HackerNews user for all this info]

When I deployed to Passenger production, it blew up on me. I solved it by restarting Apache. You may want to try the same with Nginx.

I'm not 100% sure this is the best way, or covers all the cases. Anyone else here may add or edit this to help. Good luck!